# Edit Ban Can't Go Away

Tags: bug, edits, banning

I got an edit ban, which means too many edits were rejected.

[image: picture]

It told me to try again in 7 days, but every day it still says try again in 7 days. Why's that? How can I get out of the edit ban?

Comment: Possibly an error in the message. It says your ban clears in 4 days.

Comment: Moderators can see a user's ban information.

Comment: There's a certain irony in your username and the reason you got an editng ban... :-)

Comment: @Oded [meta-tag:status-norepro] should probably be removed, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266511/the-number-of-days-in-too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days

Comment: @animuson Where can I see the ban clear date?

Comment: @X.Li Moderators have a box that tells them information about various blocks on an account. Regular users, even the owner of the account, aren't able to see it.

Comment: @animuson Then I have to check the date regularly.

Comment: Do they really use a serif font for the ban message?  Is that part of the punishment?

Answer (score 3):

Only diamond moderators can tell how long your edit ban will expire. For ordinary users, the 7-day edit ban dialogue never updated, so it always displays as 7 days.

The best way is to just remember when you got banned, and come back editing at least seven days later. Or better, review your edits, your rejected edits, and note the reasons of why your edits are rejected.