# Review queues are still unavailable after 7 day block has expired

Tags: support, review-queues

I was blocked during 7 days Now review is open but steel I can not make review on first post and late answer... **it was blocked Forever ?**

[image]

Comment: This:https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5323932, this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5302232 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5295577 are completely pointless minor edits.

Comment: It seems like almost all your suggestions are adding a single tag.  These edits were rightfully rejected for being too minor.

Comment: I understand but when it will be unblocked ?

Comment: Based on [your other question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266511/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days), you only waited 5 days.  So, try again in another 2.

Comment: OK but in message I still getting 7 days ...

Comment: about review 7 days already passed, another question is about edit NOT review ...

Comment: I'm confused, have 7 days of your suggested edits ban passed or 5? Or were you also blocked from all review queues for 7 days for another reason? Please edit the title of your question in case my assumption (and subsequent edit) were incorrect.

Comment: yes it passed and you can see what I'm getting on image in question ... 7 days issue is described here  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266511/the-number-of-days-in-too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days

Comment: Then why do you say in your other question that only 5 days have passed (like @Anonymous mentioned)?

Comment: because from edit issue 5 day was passed ... edit was banned 5 days ago , view was banned 8 days ago .

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258727/2591612

Comment: Can you just write answer and dont give me Unpleasant notes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from your comments, this is the situation:

8 days ago you were locked out of the review queues for some reason (perhaps a lot of bad reviews), for a period of 7 days.
5 days ago you were locked out of suggested edits because too many of your suggestions were rejected, for a period of 7 days. This in turn also locked you out of the review queues for 7 days.

The original review queue lockout has expired, but your suggested edits lockout has not yet expired. This is also indicated by the message. In about 2 days you should be able to access the review queues.

Timeline:

- 2014-07-15: locked out from review queues for 7 more days because of a review queue ban
- 2014-07-16: locked out from review queues for 6 more days because of a review queue ban
- 2014-07-17: locked out from review queues for 5 more days because of a review queue ban
- 2014-07-18: locked out from review queues for 4 more days because of a review queue ban, and locked out from review queues for 7 more days because of a suggested edit ban
- 2014-07-19: locked out from review queues for 3 more days because of a review queue ban, and locked out from review queues for 6 more days because of a suggested edit ban
- 2014-07-20: locked out from review queues for 2 more days because of a review queue ban, and locked out from review queues for 5 more days because of a suggested edit ban
- 2014-07-21: locked out from review queues for 1 more days because of a review queue ban, and locked out from review queues for 4 more days because of a suggested edit ban
- 2014-07-22: locked out from review queues for 3 more days because of a suggested edit ban
- 2014-07-23: locked out from review queues for 2 more days because of a suggested edit ban

Comment: you understand correctly... my question is why I can not make review (because 7 days already passed) and why message is "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days. " instead of "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 2 days."

Comment: @Anri that's another issue that might be a legitimate bug. I'll edit my answer with a timeline.