# Editing for reputation

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, privileges, rejected-edits

***Editing***

As a new programmer I'm limited to only knowing how to use the Visual Basic language which isn't really used by anyone. In this case there are never any questions about Visual Basic that I can answer. I still want to help the Stack Overflow community so I started editing questions to earn reputation.

Is this a bad thing to do? About half my edits got rejected. Could I loose privileges/reputation from a lot of rejections? Some of my edits are simply changes like changing "I am" to "I'm" and "i" to "I". Is that a unwanted edit and a waste of time?

Comment: If there's something that you genuinely believe can be improved by editing a post, then you should edit it. But changing "I am" to "I'm" doesn't improve anything, and wasting someone's time to review that edit just so you can pick up two points of reputation is not appropriate and would warrant a rejection.

Comment: *Editing For Reputation* wont lift your Q-limit/throttle, asking better questions is the way out of that hole (and/or fixing past posts).

Comment: ["Visual Basic language which isn't really used by anyone". Nope.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visual+basic)

Comment: @Joe Certainly its used, but compared against the nearly 750K C# questions, its pretty clear what most .NET developers prefer :) (All the VB tags *just* break 100K, VB.NET is at about 78K)

Comment: +1 for coming here to ask if you're wrong instead of just ranting.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Oh yeah, of course. I'm a C# dev myself and see VB as something ridiculously ugly. VB questions still exist though.

Answer (score 12):

> Is this a bad thing to do?

Not if they are good edits which truly improve the post and thus improving the site.

> Could I loose privileges/reputation from a lot of rejections?

You won't lose reputation.  However, as [Kendra](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2607247/kendra) points out in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283520/editing-for-reputation#comment142704_283522),  it is possible for [you to get some time off from editing if you have too many rejections](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258727/edit-ban-cant-go-away). Also, people will notice that you are making unnecessary edits constantly.

> Some of my edits are simply changes like changing "I am" to "I'm" and "i" to "I". Is that a unwanted edit and a waste of time?

Yes, if this is all you are changing then you aren't improving the post. While minor things should be fixed when making more prominent edits ("I am" to "I'm" isn't a difference and should be left alone) changing these alone should be avoided and reviewers should reject. It wastes the time of reviewers and it can push posts to the top unnecessarily.

Answer (score 7):

It is relatively easy to gain reputation points doing edits. And it is easy to have almost 100% suggested edits approved.

To do so you should:

- choose post which has many things needing improvement
- go carefully through the post correcting everything what is wrong
- put attention to code formatting, spelling errors
- remove noise from post ("Hello", "Thank you" etc)
- look at tags. Tags sometimes have description where they shouldn't be used

If you do this carefully you will not give reviewer alibi to vote for rejection.
When reviewer sees that you spend some time and put some effort he will surely accept such edit.

But when there is only little spelling error corrected and reviewer sees that there are many other errors untouched he may assume that you want to gain points too easily and may vote for rejection.

Comment: Not to forget a proper edit summary. "Improved formatting." does *not* cut it.

Answer (score 2):

Editing is **not wrong** provided that you are doing it if the post should be edited (like if it has language or grammar problems, not perfect formatting or one can not get the point of the post easily, not able to read). You can read about editing [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Now coming to rejection of edits, if you make very few, small changes like changing "`I am` " to " `I'm` " only in posts then they will not approve your edit. And this type of post only wastes time, for you as well as for reviewers.